# DataTables: date range filter triggers error (sever-side processing)

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter, datatables, server-side

I'm new to [datatables](/questions/tagged/datatables). I'm following [this](https://www.webslesson.info/2017/06/date-range-search-in-datatables-using-php-ajax.html) tutorial. I get data from table using this example:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable();

$('#example tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
console.log( table.row( this ).data() );
} );
```

I got data if I try to click row and send data to my modal, but if I try to filter date range I can't get my data from row and get error:

> undefined asfa:623 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of
>   undefined     at HTMLTableRowElement. (try:623)    at
>   HTMLTableSectionElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:2)    at
>   HTMLTableSectionElement.v.handle (jquery.min.js:2)

This is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    const property_datepicker = {
        format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
        todayHighlight: true,
        autoclose: true,
        clearBtn: true,
    }
    $('#from_date').datepicker(property_datepicker);
    $('#to_date').datepicker(property_datepicker);
    filter_date('no');
    function filter_date(is_date_search, from_date, to_date) {
        var my_table = $('#dataTable').DataTable({
                lengthMenu: [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]],
                dom: 'Bflrtip',
                buttons: [{
                        extend: 'print',
                        title: '',
                        className: 'btn btn-primary',
                        footer: true,
                        exportOptions: {
                            columns: [0, ':visible']
                        }
                    }, {
                        extend: 'pdf',
                        title: '',
                        className: 'btn btn-primary',
                        footer: true,
                    }, {
                        extend: 'excel',
                        title: '',
                        className: 'btn btn-primary',
                        footer: true,
                    }, 'colvis'],
                processing: true,
                serverSide: true,
                order: [],
                ajax: {
                    url: "<?= base_url('data_lama/fetchdata_bayar'); ?>",
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: {
                        is_date_search: is_date_search,
                        from_date: from_date,
                        to_date: to_date,
                    }
                },
                ColumnDefs: [{
                        'target': [0, 3, 4],
                        'orderable': false,
                    }
                ],
                "aoColumnDefs": [{
                        "aTargets": [7],
                        "mRender": function (data, type, row) {
                            var formmatedvalue = new Intl.NumberFormat().format(data);
                            return formmatedvalue;
                        },
                    }, {
                        "aTargets": [8],
                        "mRender": function (data, type, row) {
                            var formmatedvalue = new Intl.NumberFormat().format(data);
                            return formmatedvalue;
                        },
                    }, {
                        "aTargets": [9],
                        "mRender": function (data, type, row) {
                            var formmatedvalue = new Intl.NumberFormat().format(data);
                            return formmatedvalue;
                        },
                    }, {
                        "aTargets": [10],
                        "mRender": function (data, type, row) {
                            var formmatedvalue = new Intl.NumberFormat().format(data);
                            return formmatedvalue;
                        },
                    }, {
                        "aTargets": [11],
                        "mRender": function (data, type, row) {
                            var formmatedvalue = new Intl.NumberFormat().format(data);
                            return formmatedvalue;
                        },
                    }, {
                        "aTargets": [15],
                        "mRender": function (data, type, row) {
                            var btn_actions = '<div class="btn-group"><button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-info dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Actions</button><div class="dropdown-menu"><a class="dropdown-item" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#formModal" href="#">Update</a><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a><div class="dropdown-divider"></div><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a></div></div>';
                            return btn_actions;
                        },
                    }, ],
            });
        $('#dataTable tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
            var data = my_table.row(this).data();
            console.log(data);
            $('#titleModal').html('Change Data');
            $('.modal-footer button[type=submit]').html('ChangeData');
            $('#ACC').val(data[1]);
            $('#tglyar').val(data[2]);
            $('#ang').val(data[3]);
            $('#tgltem').val(data[4]);
            $('#sdh').val(data[5]);
            $('#col').val(data[6]);
            $('#bangs').val(data[7]);
            $('#pokok').val(data[8]);
            $('#lapen').val(data[9]);
            $('#cc').val(data[10]);
            $('#saldo').val(data[11]);
            $('#ecd').val(data[12]);
            $('#mgn').val(data[13]);
            $('#operator').val(data[14]);
        });
    }
    $('#filter').click(function () {
        const from_date = $('#from_date').val();
        const to_date = $('#to_date').val();
        if (from_date != '' && to_date != '') {
            $('#dataTable').DataTable().destroy();
            filter_date('yes', from_date, to_date);
        } else {
            alert('tidak ada data');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you update response also in Question

Comment: @B.K im sorry sir I don't understand what you mean. what queston update? please I need help.

Comment: @Arteesy response is what your JSON data generated from server. You can inspect response from browser (right click inspect and check network tab)